# How to get count of a column between a certain date range without changing the Where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, date, group-by, count, pivot

I have a table that has account number, group category and date.

I have a query that does this

```
Select count(AccNum)
FROM Table
Where date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-03-31'
AND
group IN ('groupA','groupB')
```

Now is there any way for me to make it work like this

```
Select count(AccNum) Where date between 2020-02-01 AND '2020-02-31' AS CountFebuary, count(AccNum) Where date between 2020-03-01 AND '2020-02-31' AS CountMarch,
FROM Table
Where date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-03-31'
AND
group IN ('groupA','groupB')
```

I want to be able to get the total count of accounts for each month without writing a separate query for it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(case when date >= '2020-02-01' and date < '2020-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_february,
    sum(case when date >= '2020-03-01' and date < '2020-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_march
from mytable
where 
    date >= '2020-02-01' and date < '2020-04-01'
    and group IN ('groupA','groupB')
```

Since you only want two months of data, then we can shorten the conditional expressions a little:

```
select 
    sum(case when date <  '2020-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_february,
    sum(case when date >= '2020-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_march
from mytable
where 
    date >= '2020-02-01' and date < '2020-04-01'
    and group IN ('groupA','groupB')
```

If you are running MySQL, we can shorten some more:

```
select 
    sum(date <  '2020-03-01') cnt_february,
    sum(date >= '2020-03-01') cnt_march
from mytable
where 
    date >= '2020-02-01' and date < '2020-04-01'
    and group IN ('groupA','groupB')
```

Side note: `group` is a reserved word in most databases, hence not a good choice for a column name.